# jQuery UI Sortable in scrolling div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable

This question is *not* about horizontal scrolling.  It is about using the jQuery UI `sortable` functionality when it is in a horizontally scrolled area.

I have created a fiddle as a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/shhQuiet/t2vnfmh4/4/embedded/result/

I have tried something like this, to no avail:

```
$('#scroller').scroll(function() {
    $('.items').sortable("refreshPositions");
});
```

Here are the deets:

**markup**

```
<div id="scroller">
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">One</div>
    <div class="item">Two</div>
    <div class="item">Three</div>
    <div class="item">Four</div>
    <div class="item">Five</div>
    <div class="item">Six</div>
</div>
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">One</div>
    <div class="item">Two</div>
    <div class="item">Three</div>
    <div class="item">Four</div>
    <div class="item">Five</div>
    <div class="item">Six</div>
</div>
... removed some repetitions for brevity ...
</div>
</p>
```

**JS**

```
$('.items').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    containment: 'parent'
});
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
    border: 1px #aaa solid;
    width: 2in;
}

.items {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#scroller {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: So what is not working/the issue?

Comment: The issue is that when dragging, the element being dragged does not retain its horizontal position, it drags as though it is still in the original position.  Play with the fiddle and follow the instructions and you should see the behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too late now since you've already accepted an answer, but I solved the very same problem by adding this to the sortable config:

```
start: function (event, ui) {
    ui.helper.css('left', ui.originalPosition.left);
}
```

Comment: I will try your answer tomorrow and if it works I'll change my accepted answer :). Thanks!

Comment: I had to set margin-left instead of left, to the current scroll value, but great work-around. +1

Answer (score 0):

Bro, it is because the sortable plugin get the position value without considering the `scrolltop` and `scrollleft` positions of the element that is getting dragged. You have to change the `jquery-ui.js` code to alter and overcome the fault.

Comment: If you want anymore clarification, juzz comment.